# How can you define a persistent variable in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project, and what I would like to do is be able to create a reference to a variable defined in `urls.py` that is kept for the duration of the process.

I've tried an approach using global vars - but for whatever reason, the value of the variable in `urls.py` is the initial value - even if I change it somewhere else. I've followed the concepts as explained [here](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules), but just doesn't work.

However, when I try such a scenario outside of Django, it works as expected.

I think I'm missing a trick (or two) with Django - it's great, I'm new to it, and I think I'm going down the wrong path. Should I be using the caching stuff included with Django to store the variable, or is that even more off track?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Have you read about the `global` statement yet?  Can you provide code for this "I've tried an approach using global vars"?  Most importantly, however, is "Why?" and "What are you trying to accomplish?"  90% of the time, you just need a new value in `settings.py`.  But maybe not.  Provide your use case, please, also.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with S.Lott's comment, your question is a little vague.  I think you're trying to reference some variable defined in urls?  You know you can import urls.py into any other python script as long as it's on your PYTHONPATH.   Assuming you're talking about a Django view when you say a "process", you could import a URL directly into a view function:

```
def foo_view(request):
    from bar_app.urls import BAR_URL_PATTERN
```

Please give us more information on your specific use case, and I'll amend my answer to give you a better response.

Good Luck! I hope you're enjoying your first foray into the wonderful world of Django!